# Android: Cannot send UPnP packet from computer to Android device

Tags: android, upnp

I have a computer connected to my router (via ethernet cable) and an android phone running Jellybean v4.2.2 connected to my network via WiFi. On my computer, I have a UPnP server running, and on my phone, I have a control point application running that I am currently writing using Cling Core. For some reason, when my control point application starts up, it can reach my computer and send it an M-SEARCH message, however, my computer cannot reach my phone with a reply. In fact, when I ping my phone's IP address from my computer I get "Destination Host Is Unreachable." However, if I open the browser on my phone, the phone suddenly becomes visible on the network, I am able to ping it, and it can receive discovery replies from my computer. Under my advanced WiFi settings, I have "Keep WiFi on during sleep" set to "Always." I also have the following permissions set in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Why would opening the phone browser make my phone visible to other devices?